# fb:pronoun tag not working

Tags: facebook, xfbml

I have a canvas iFrame app that's uses xfbml tags.

They all work fine except for fb:pronoun

Was this tag deprecated? If so, whats the correct replacement?

Comment: But What is the problem? What is not working? Getting some error? Please edit your question, post some code snipt that you are using and your error detials.

Answer (score 1):

This page says that you can use it in xfbml:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/pronoun/

But it's not working for me either, using this text:
`<fb:pronoun uid="678640076" useyou="true" possessive="true" capitalize ="false"></fb:pronoun>`

I've created a bug report, please vote for it:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/240519622664534